# What to do if a pregnant mother dies with a baby in her womb?

Tags: fiqh, shia-sunni, baby, pregnancy

In this case should the baby be taken out with surgery or mother should be buried with the baby?

Is there any verse or hadith in this regard?

Please specify your answer in according to your school of Fiqh (Hanafi, Shafei, Hanbali, Maliki, Jafari)

Comment: To clarify: Are you assuming the baby is dead, too?  Or assuming there is a chance the baby may be saved if it is removed?

Comment: @Flimzy there is a chance the baby may be saved if it is removed. but if both situation is answered its better

Answer (score 2):

In Islam human life is very valuable. Saving someone's life is like saving the whole mankind. The baby inside dead mom is a separate human being. If mom dies the baby must be saved.

> Because of that, We decreed upon the Children of Israel that whoever
> kills a soul unless for a soul or for corruption [done] in the land -
> it is as if he had slain mankind entirely. And whoever saves one - it
> is as if he had saved mankind entirely. And our messengers had
> certainly come to them with clear proofs. Then indeed many of them,
> [even] after that, throughout the land, were transgressors.
>
> Surat Al-Maidah[5:32]